# ShareFile user invite to Podio workspace using API

Tags: c#, .net, podio, sharefile

We are trying to add members to a Podio workspace using API. We are able to do this in normal Podio with level 2 API key.

But the same code is throwing the following error when we try to do this in Sharefile Podio (authenticated with ShareFile account).

```
Endpoint : /space/{space_id}/member/ 
Method : POST 
Response :
```

> {"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http://api.podio.com/space/xxxxxx/member/","query_string":"","method":"POST"},"error_description":"The
>   user with id xxxxx does not have the right add_user_light on space
>   with id xxxxx","error":"forbidden"}

The users we are trying to invite are already in Sharefile and is possible to invite through the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the problem was with the user's Role setting.

The user was a customer in Sharefile and we were trying to set the user's role as 'light' from the code.

> We fixed it by setting the role into 'regular' Or 'admin'.